# Image is not displayed in proper format in ionic application using $cordovaImagePicker plugin

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I want to access gallery images on the click of attach button on top right (Gallery is accessed on click and we can select the images also but the problem occurs while posting the selected image)

[image: screenshot].

**html code**

```
<div class="col" style="margin: 3% 0% 0% 0%;" >
   <img src="../img/ic_message_attach.png" align="right" 
     ng-click ="attachImage()"> 
</div>
<div ng-repeat = "image in imageList">
    <img ng-src="{{image}}">
</div>
```

**js code**

```
$scope.selectImage = function () {
    $scope.imageList = [];
   var options = {
       maximumImagesCount: 10,
       width: 300,
       height: 300,
       quality: 100
   };
   $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)

       .then(function (results) {   
        console.log('gallery data: ' + angular.toJson(results));
           console.log(results);
           for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
               $scope.imageList.push(angular.toJson(results[i]));
           }
       }, function (error) {
           console.log(error);
       });
  };
```

Comment: What is console.log(results); is printing? Please past the whole thing here

Comment: Also why do you have `$scope.imageList = results;` AND `for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
               $scope.imageList.push(results[i]);
           }` ? Remove `$scope.imageList = results;`

Comment: for loop is used for multiple images intake from gallery.
 Here are the logs:- 
 log  gallery data: ["file:///data/data/com.ionicframework.ionicmaterialdesign392344/cache/tmp_IMG-20160922-WA00061823784707.jpg","file:///data/data/com.ionicframework.ionicmaterialdesign392344/cache/tmp_IMG-20160922-WA0002132329065.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the app in while doing ionic run android? If so, try building the app using ionic build copy the apk to phone, and then try instaling and running the app. It seems like a cache issue. Also dont forget to uninstall the app completely before installing it again.

Comment: After apk installation, I am getting white screen on application launch.